# Find the smallest $c \ge \frac{1}{\pi^2}$ such that $\int_a^b (f(t))^2\, dt \le c(b-a)^2 \int_a^b (f'(t))^2\, dt$ for all $f\in C^1_0[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

> Let $k\in \Bbb N$, $a,b\in \Bbb R$, $a < b$, and $C_0^k[a,b] = \{f\in C^k(a,b) \cap C[a,b]: f(a) = f(b) = 0\}$. Find the *smallest* $c\in \left[\frac{1}{\pi^2}, \frac12\right]$ such that
> $$\int_a^b (f(t))^2\, dt \le c(b-a)^2 \int_a^b (f'(t))^2\, dt$$
> for all $f\in C^1_0[a,b]$.

First of all, I could show that the constant $c$ must satisfy $c \ge \frac{1}{\pi^2}$. To do this, one simply considers the function $f(x) = \sin \left(\frac{\pi(x-a)}{b-a} \right)$. Clearly, $f\in C^1_0[a,b]$. How do I precisely find a constant that works? Seeing some similar questions online, one of my ideas is to extend $f \in C_0^1[a,b]$ to a $(b-a)$ periodic function on $\Bbb R$, and do some analysis then. The solutions seem to lean towards Fourier-analytic methods, so I'm wondering if it's possible to find the right $c$ without them.

Comment: "Find $c\in \left[\frac{1}{\pi^2}, \frac12\right]$ s.t. $A\le cB,\;\forall f\dots$" is equivalent to "Prove that $A\le\frac12B,\;\forall f\dots$". Do you mean "find the smallest $c\in\Bbb R$ s.t. $A\le cB,\;\forall f\dots$"?

Comment: @AnneBauval Indeed, that's correct!

Comment: Since you proved that $c$ *must* satisfy $c\ge1/\pi^2,$ why not just formulate the question as "Find the smallest $c\in\Bbb R$ such that..."?

Comment: You can improve the bound slightly to $c\geq 1/10$ by using $f(x)=(x-a)(b-x)$. (It may also be helpful to set $a=0$, by translation invariance)

Comment: @AnneBauval I wanted to show why it makes sense to consider the lower bound on $c$ in the first place.

Comment: Isn't that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions#Second_version ?

Comment: @MartinR We don't know if that's the best constant, right?

Comment: Your example $f(x) = \sin \left(\frac{\pi(x-a)}{b-a} \right)
$ shows that it is the best constant

Comment: @MartinR Correct me if I'm wrong, but for $1/\pi^2$ to be the best constant, we need to know that it is the best constant in the *particular case* of $f(x) = \sin(\ldots)$ also. Right?

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic: Wirtinger's inequality (second version) shows that $\int_a^b (f(t))^2\, dt \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{\pi^2} \int_a^b (f'(t))^2\, dt$ holds for all differentiable functions with $f(a)=f(b) = 0$, and equality holds for the function $f(x) = \sin \left(\frac{\pi(x-a)}{b-a} \right)$. Therefore $c = 1/\pi^2$ is the best possible constant.

Comment: I see, thanks for helping out! @MartinR